# How to programmatically set edit text hint in android?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Is there a way to set the text hint displayed inside of an android edittext with java? I would like for my app to be able to display different things in the edittext at different times.

Comment: Before asking these kind of question just refer the Android Developer side For EditText Link is HERE http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html

Answer (score 86):

Did you try the [setHint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setHint%28int%29)?

```
myTextView.setHint("My conditional hint");
```

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 46):

If you are using simple `Editext` without `TextInputLayout` :

```
EditText etUsername;
etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
etUsername.setHint("Your Hint");
```

If you are using `Editext` within `TextInputLayout` then you need to change property of `TextInputLayout` not `Edittext`:

```
TextInputLayout layoutUser;
layoutUser = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.inputLayoutUname);
layoutUser.setHint(getResources().getString(R.string.hintFaculty));
```

Answer (score 17):

Call [`setHint()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setHint%28int%29) on the `EditText`.

Answer (score 9):

```
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourEditTextId)).setHint("hint text");
```

Answer (score 5):

**Kotlin**

```
editText.hint = "Your hint"
```

Answer (score 3):

if you are using actionbarsherlock searchview, this is the best way to set string dynamically

```
   AutoCompleteTextView searchTextView =
                    (AutoCompleteTextView) mSearchView.findViewById(R.id.abs__search_src_text);

searchTextView.setHint(getResources().getString(R.string.search));
```

Answer (score 1):

**In Kotlin**

```
val layoutMobile: TextInputLayout = findViewById<View>(R.id.inputLayout_MobileNumber) as TextInputLayout
        layoutMobile.hint = "Your Hint"
```

Answer (score 0):

for editText.hint you must delete name of your edit.Text from activity_main.xml then set in the MainActivity in java or activity_main.xml because text is preferred to hint.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <EditText
     android:id="@+id/text"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:inputType="textMultiLine|textLongMessage"
     android:hint="\n"/>
```

To be honest I don´t understand why.. but including "\n" as hint in the xml did the trick!

Now you can call setHint from Java code:

```
searchEditText.setHint(getString(R.string.search_hint));
```

and remove the \n from strings.xml if you want to allow the text split automatically according to the room

```
<string name="search_hint">keyword, location, max price (e.g. 1K, 1M)</string>
```

Answer (score -1):

in Java

```
yourEditTex.setText("");//First
yourEditTex.hit("Your text");
```

this for alls cases.

Answer (score -4):

You can try following,

in Java

```
yourEditText.setHint("hint");
```

in Kotlin

```
yourEditText.hint = "Your hint"
```