# How to change android:hint dynamically?

Tags: java, android

I want to change android:hint depending on each model.
(Android device might have different sdcard path. I want to set this value.)

How can I get the element or change the attribute?

Such as

Preferences.java

```
public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity {
    private void setDeviceSDCardPath () {
        String defaultPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath();
        pref = getElementById(R.preferences.pref_id);   // <--- invalid, but I want to do like this
        pref.hint = "ex.) " + defaultPath; // <-- also invalid
    }
}
```

preferences.xml

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/title">
     <EditTextPreference
            android:id="@+id/pref_id"
            android:key="pref_key"
            android:title="@string/pref_title"
            android:summary="@string/pref_summary"
            android:hint="/storage/sdcard"
            android:defaultValue="/storage/sdcard/Download/"/>
</PreferenceCategory>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [programmatically set edit text hint in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153213/programmatically-set-edit-text-hint-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the javadoc for EditTextPreference:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/EditTextPreference.html

> It is a subclass of DialogPreference and shows the EditText in a
>   dialog. This EditText can be modified either programmatically via
>   getEditText(), or through XML by setting any EditText attributes on
>   the EditTextPreference.

When you got the EditText object by using getEditText() on your EditTextPreference object you can simply use setHint(String message) method. I believe this should work:

```
EditTextPreference editPref = (EditTextPreference) findPreference(R.id.pref_id);
editPref.getEditText().setHint(message);
```

Comment: Yes I want to get EditTextPreference. But IDE says "the method is deprecated" and R.id.pref_id cannot be applied.

Comment: On newer version of android you should use the fragments. The method for findPreference is now PreferenceFragment instead of PreferenceActivity. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html on versions after Honeycomb 3.0 your should replace PreferenceActivity with PreferenceFragment.

Comment: The Preferences class already include a class extends PreferenceFragment.

Comment: The PreferenceFragment has a method called findPreference, Its the one you should use.

Answer (score 1):

```
your_editText.setHint("Your New hint");
```

Check this [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setHint%28int%29)

Answer (score 1):

```
myTextView.setHint("My conditional hint");
```

Comment: If your answer is same as anyone else's then you should up vote it rather than posting the same solution again. This is how stackoverflow works. And your answer is copied from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153213/programmatically-set-edit-text-hint-in-android. When you do so, you should give the reference.

Comment: ok bro i do accept what u say,but i thought no one answered , but you posted few seconds early , i did't see it.. and i answered .

Comment: How to get myTextView?

Comment: EditText myEditText= (EditText) FindViewByID(R.id.nameEditText);

or 

TextView myEditText= (TextView ) FindViewByID(R.id.nameTextText);

Answer (score 0):

yout_editText.**setSummary**("*some description to your preference edit text*");
in xml: android:defaultValue or android:summary