# Is it possible to display my error message in hint, on android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have sets of fields for my sign up page, the design given is too narrow. Fields are close to each other the doesn't have space. i'd like to display my error message in the hint of every fields.

Is it possible? And how?

Comment: when is the error message displays?? when user type something wrong or by default you want to show the error message

Comment: Have you tried the setError method of EditText?

Comment: when the fields are left empty or doesn't meet the expectations on java.

Comment: just want to try to set my errors on hints, is it possible? setError sets on the side of my edittext and kinda mess with my design

Comment: Possible duplicate of [programmatically set edit text hint in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153213/programmatically-set-edit-text-hint-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the setHint method? You can change the hints of the fields that are in error and even change the hint color to red or whatever works best with your design.

```
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourEditTextId)).setHint("Oops! Try again.");
```

[setHint Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setHint%28int%29)

[Answer explanation on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25948276/5224040)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing Sign Up Process, So you used Edittext.

For Edittext used this,

```
 EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        editText.setError("Enter the Valid UserName");
```