# how to set EditText hint dynamically?

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, android-edittext

Below is my activity. I am calling this activity via Intent on click on Two diffrent buttons. Now what I want that when I open Below activity on click on first button then I want to show hint in edittext "Po No new" and when I open below activity on click on second button then I want to show hint in edittext "Po No old". How can I acieve this ?

Xml file -

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    android:text="Po no."
                    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/txtPoNo"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:completionThreshold="3"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/txtMeterSrMo"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

             </LinearLayout>
</ScrollLayout>
```

Activity file -

```
public class InstallationDashBoardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.categories_activity);

        txtPoNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPoNo);

    }
}
```

Button Click -

```
installation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent intent = new Intent(ServiceCategories.this,InstallationDashBoardActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("isNew", true);
            startActivity(intent);


        }
    });

replacement.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ServiceCategories.this,InstallationDashBoardActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("isNew", false);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

I place below Code in my fragment onCreateView -

```
//Getting Extras
        if(getActivity().getIntent().getExtras()!=null){
            isNew = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("isNew");
        }

        // Added condition here
        if(isNew) {
            txtPoNo.setHint("Po No New");
        }
        else {
            txtPoNo.setHint("Po No Old");
        }
```

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9153245/5241603

Comment: Possible duplicate of [programmatically set edit text hint in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153213/programmatically-set-edit-text-hint-in-android)

Comment: How can i detect which button is clicked because i want to set diffrent hint on single edittext ?

Answer (score 1):

@ Moin Khan try this , hope this can help you

```
installation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ServiceCategories.this, InstallationDashBoardActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("key", "value");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    replacement.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ServiceCategories.this, InstallationDashBoardActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

and in second activity

```
 Intent intent2 = getIntent();
    String strKey = intent2.getStringExtra("key");
    if (strKey.equalsIgnoreCase("value")) {
        txtPoNo.setHint("Po No New");
    } else {
        txtPoNo.setHint("Po No Old");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Call

```
txtPoNo.setHint("Po No Old");
```

**Update**

You meant you want to detect which button is clicked and according to that you want to show hint right? For that very simple pass one boolean flag with intent and try to identify using that boolean value

```
installation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent intent = new Intent(ServiceCategories.this,InstallationDashBoardActivity.class);

                //Added flag here
                intent.putExtras("isNew", true);
                startActivity(intent);


            }
        });

replacement.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ServiceCategories.this,InstallationDashBoardActivity.class);

                //Added flag here
                intent.putExtras("isNew", false);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Get boolean value in your activity

```
public class InstallationDashBoardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//boolean added
public boolean isNew;
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.categories_activity);

            //Getting Extras
            if(getIntent().getExtras()!=null){
               isNew = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("isNew");
             }

            txtPoNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPoNo);

            // Added condition here
            if(isNew)
              txtPoNo.setHint("Po No New");
            else
               txtPoNo.setHint("Po No Old");

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Jai for your response but how can I change hint when I opened this activity on first button click ?

Comment: It is showing only "Po No Old" in both Button click

Comment: Evrytime IsNew is false.

Comment: @MoinKhan : When you will click on installation button it will be true

Comment: Yes you are right but I dubug your code and check that when I click  Installation button then also isNew is false. thats why it is showing "Po No Old".

Comment: @MoinKhan : It shouldn't return false if you clicked on installation button check properly you initialize and passing differnent value in both button's click

Comment: @MoinKhan : Also check that you are not setting hint at any other place in your activity rather than only if condition

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124387/discussion-between-jai-and-moin-khan).

Comment: @MoinKhan : Could you update your code in your question after you did change? So I could see and help you with that

Comment: Hi jai, check my Updated question.

Comment: @MoinKhan : Paste you full activity and fragment code please

Comment: @MoinKhan : Because here there is confusion about from which activity you are calling intent and to which activity are you going?

Answer (score 0):

```
  editText.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            editText.setHint("");
            return false;
        }

    });

    editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus){
                editText.setHint("Hint");
            }
        }
    });
```