# How change upper-hint in MaterialDesign EditText?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, hint

I use TextInputEditText and kotlin. I try to change hint programaticaly. But it changed just in box. Add when move-up when i wrote something - upper hint not showing.

I use this code in onCreate:

```
editTextChooseDate.hint = "Please choose the Date"
```

and later I check if editTextChooseDate has some test and try to change hint by:

```
 editTextChooseDate.hint = "Selected Date"
```

There is editTextChooseDate in xml:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutEditTextChooseDate"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextChooseDate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:maxLines="1"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

I expected to change upper-hint programaticaly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set second `hint` to `layoutEditTextChooseDate` instead of `editTextChooseDate`. Because "upper-hint" as you called it, is a part of parent container `TextInputLayout`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are making the change on the main thread.

Check this question: [programmatically set edit text hint in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153213/programmatically-set-edit-text-hint-in-android)

As it's certainly possible.